# Как вывести элементы в одну строку HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net

Как вывести элементы text box и звездочку на экране друг за другом в одну строку?
А сообщение об ошибке ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
        <td><input class="text-box form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Это поле является обязательным" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value=""><span class="notification"> *</span><br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</td>
```

Comment: что именно должно быть в линию?

Comment: @Air textbox и звездочка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.error {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input class="text-box form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Это поле является обязательным" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
  <span class="notification"> *</span>
  <span class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</span>
</td>
```